# UWP DataContext from DataTempalte to UserControl in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I want to share a ListViewItem from DataTemplate to a UserControl in DataTemplate using DataContext, i just spend two hours on this task, looked many sites, but dont find a requested answer, because everytime i want to get DataContext, it is null.

Short code, what i want to do:

In Page.xaml

```
<ListView Name="MainWindowLinesInfoListView1" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="MainWindowLinesInfoListView1_ItemClick" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind pk1}" SelectionMode="Single">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Przystanki">
                <local:MainWindowLinesInfoFirst DataContext="{x:Bind self}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

in UserControl called: MainWindowLinesInfoFirst

```
<Grid Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock x:Name="MainWindowLinesInfoListView1TextBlock" Foreground="Navy" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
```

and in .cs of this UserControl:

```
public MainWindowLinesInfoFirst()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var a = this.DataContext as Przystanki;
}
```

and here is a simple class:

```
public class Przystanki
{
    public Przystanki self { get { return this; } }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, that always when a this UserControl is called, a DataContext is not a "Przystanki" bot null.

Question is: How to send a DataContext to this UserControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What UWP does:

1. Creates `MainWindowLinesInfoFirst` control.
2. Sets its `DataContext` property to your required value.

Obviously, you can't read `DataContext` property in the constructor, because the control isn't created yet and there's no way for UWP to set a property before creating an instance.

What you want is to subscribe to the `DataContextChanged` event in the constructor. When UWP sets it, you'll be notified.

Comment: still null..  using `this.DataContextChanged += (sender, e) => { var a = this.DataContext as Przystanki; };` and `<local:MainWindowLinesInfoFirst />`

Comment: AH! Catch it! Thanks ! I just didnt used arguments and i had to check if isnt null!  `var a = e.NewValue as Przystanki;` and `if (a != null) ChangeText(a);` And works beatiful ! My master; 3

Comment: but why is it set back to null afterwards without notifying through DataContextChangd